# Getting error in PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm newbie in PL/SQL and I have problem with the following code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER secure_employees DISABLE;

ALTER TABLE employees ( ADD (exceed_avgsal VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'NO' 
 CONSTRAINT employees_exceed_avgsal_ck CHECK (exceed_avgsal IN ('YES', 'NO')));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_avgsal IS
  avgsal_exceeded employees.exceed_avgsal%type;
  CURSOR emp_csr IS
    SELECT employee_id, job_id, salary FROM employees FOR UPDATE;
  e_resource_busy EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_resource_busy, -54);

  FUNCTION get_job_avgsal(jobid VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    avg_sal employees.salary%type;
  BEGIN
    SELECT (max_salary + min_salary) / 2
      INTO avg_sal
      FROM jobs
     WHERE job_id = jobid;
    RETURN avg_sal;
  END;
BEGIN
  FOR emprec IN emp_csr LOOP
    avgsal_exceeded := 'NO';
    IF emprec.salary >= get_job_avgsal(emprec.job_id) THEN
      avgsal_exceeded := 'YES';
    END IF;
    UPDATE employees
       SET exceed_avgsal = avgsal_exceeded
     WHERE CURRENT OF emp_csr;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN e_resource_busy THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Record is busy, try later.');
END check_avgsal;

EXECUTE check_avgsal 

SELECT e.employee_id, e.job_id, (j.max_salary-j.min_salary/2) job_avgsal, e.salary, e.exceed_avgsal avg_exceeded 
 FROM employees e, jobs j WHERE e.job_id = j.job_id and e.exceed_avgsal = 'YES';
COMMIT;
```

I get the error message

> PROCEDURE CHECK_AVGSAL compiled
>   Errors: check compiler log

If anyone can help me I will be thankful

Comment: And what does the **compiler log** say?

Comment: The error you are getting is just a compiler message saying that there are errors. You have to do a `SELECT * FROM user_errors WHERE name='CHECK_AVGSAL'` to see the actual errors. Please post those ones here.

Comment: Error(36,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE"

Comment: Again the same problem Error(36,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE"

Comment: How are you running this? All as one script? Looks like it's treating the `execute` line as part of the procedure. If it's all executed together then you need a `/` on a line on its own after the `end chk_avgsal`, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Also have that : Error(39,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE" when expecting one of the following:     * & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and    or group having intersect minus order start union where    connect || multiset

Comment: yes , all as one script

Comment: Where is `'/'` ?? it pushes ur queries into DB actually..

Comment: i repair it , but getting : 
get Error(2,17): PL/SQL: Item ignored Error(2,27): PLS-00302: component 'EXCEED_AVGSAL' must be declared Error(21,1): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed : PL/SQL: Statement ignored Error(23,1): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed : PL/SQL: Statement ignored : PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored : PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "AVGSAL_EXCEEDED": invalid identifier PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Comment: Also you don't need a `COMMIT` after your last `SELECT` statement as long as `SELECT` doesn't start a transaction.

Comment: If this is not just a learning exercise then you should note that this procedure could easily be replaced by a view which just lists the employee id's that exceed the median salary, or which returns employee id's and the ratio of their salary to the median.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `/` on a line on its own, between the `end chk_avgsal;` and the next statement, [to run the PL/SQL block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663):

```
...
END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION WHEN e_resource_busy THEN ROLLBACK; 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Record is busy, try later.');
END check_avgsal;
/

EXECUTE check_avgsal 
...
```

Your `alter table` syntax is wrong too:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD (exceed_avgsal VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'NO',
  CONSTRAINT employees_exceed_avgsal_ck CHECK (exceed_avgsal IN ('YES', 'NO')));
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea834/1).

Comment: and get Error(2,17): PL/SQL: Item ignored
Error(2,27): PLS-00302: component 'EXCEED_AVGSAL' must be declared
Error(21,1): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Error(21,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(23,1): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "AVGSAL_EXCEEDED": invalid identifier
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Comment: Your `alter table` is failing - that will shown as you execute the script! - so the new column doesn't exist when the procedure is compiled. If this is a one-off you could do this as an anonymous block rather than creating a stored proc; or as Wenfried says, with a simole update statement - no PL/SQL needed.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolon:

```
EXECUTE check_avgsal;
```

But you could do it in a simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE employees e
    SET avgsal_exceeded = (
WITH avg_salaries AS 
    (SELECT (max_salary + min_salary)/2 AS avg_sal, job_id FROM jobs)
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN employee_id >= avg_sal THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
    END
FROM avg_salaries
    WHERE a.job_id = e.job_id);
```

Comment: I've repaired the semicolon but have that : SQL Error: ORA-00904: "E"."EXCEED_AVGSAL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
commited

Comment: You did not add column EXCEED_AVGSAL to employees table.